# Why pnorm function and sum of dnorm function differs for same input?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Data is height of men in 'inches'. 
Mean is 70. 
SD is 3.3 
I wanted to compute the probability of men whose height is in between 69 inches and 74 inches.

The following methods gave me different results.

```
1-(pnorm(69, 70, 3.3, lower.tail = TRUE)) - (pnorm(74, 70, 3.3, lower.tail = FALSE))
```

was equal to **0.5063336**

while

```
sum(dnorm(69:74, 70, 3.3))
```

was equal to **0.5903953**

What am I going wrong ? Which is the right approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't integrating across a continuous distribution by passing only the integers `69:74` to `dnorm()`. Try using the `integrate()` function instead:

```
integrate(function(x) dnorm(x, 70, 3.3), lower = 69, upper = 74)
```

Which returns

```
0.5063336 with absolute error < 5.6e-15
```